# Table view is empty - there's an image view from somewhere at the front of the view hieararchy

Tags: ios

I was puzzled why my table view is completely blank, despite the fact it should contain content. So I expanded the view hierarchy and can see there is some image view at the front:

[image]

See how there's a blue bar the far right of the diagram - thats an image view:

[image]

What is this and how can it be there? Its not part of my view controller, and I'm not doing anything like inserting views at runtime or anything, its just a regular table view all done via the storyboard. How can I find out what this is and how its getting there?

But apart from wondering what it is, its not covering the table view, so what reasons could there be for nothing being displayed? As can be seen there's  content there in the hierarchy yet there's nothing at all visible in the table view - I just get the red nav bar with white screen below it.

I suspect I won't be able to get an answer to these issues directly, but if anybody has any debugging tips for finding out where this image view is coming from, or how to analyse and debug the hieararchy they'd be appreciated.

Comment: would you share your project so that i can take a deeper look?

Comment: Thanks for the offer but its too big and its sensitive.

Comment: imageViews when they get declared are transparent. Perhaps it's related to something else.

Comment: ok. i guessed so. then it is hard to tell what's going wrong though. regarding the imageview... transparent or opaque does not really care in that case since it has a width of 2.5. should not cover too much of the screen... :)

Comment: did you try something like `bringToFront` on your tableview? for example in `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: @AndréSlotta Adding view.bringSubviewToFront(tableView) doesn't change anything.

Comment: The imageViews frame is only 2.5 pixels wide, It is odd if you don't know why its there, but it shouldn't be the main cause of your tableView not showing. Check through your code and interface builder for .hidden to true or setting alpha to 0 on your custom cells. Do you see seperator insets?

Comment: @NSGangster, I've checked all the view hierarchy in the storyboard and alpha is 1 for everything (I haven't been changing these though), nor is it being set in code, nor hidden. I don't see the separator insets. I just see white (even if I change the background color of the table view to something)

Comment: Can you include your code in `cellForRow:`?

Comment: It's the scroll indicator for your table view.

Comment: @beyowulf. Of course! obvious in hindsight.

Comment: @NSGangster, added, its pretty straightforward though, except its using a call for a header instead of an actual header.

Comment: BTW, I know you solved this with a reboot, but if you get this again, look at where it was in the view hierarchy (notably, which view is its `superview`) and you can narrow down the source of the view. The graphical view debugger isn't so helpful in these cases, so either show the "debug view" hierarchy in the panel to the left, or enter `expr -l objc++ -O -- [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]` at the `(lldb)` debugger prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Damn you XCode, wasted a couple of hours of my life.

All I did was exit XCode and relaunch it, and lo an behold it suddenly started working.

Comment: Classic haha. I'll remove my answer since it didn't help at all. But I only answered because I wanted to show you the screenshot. the same thing happened to me 3 days ago where my alpha got set to 0.